How to remove window title bar in Ubuntu 24.04 (GNOME 46) while keeping window controls?
I'm trying to remove the window title bar in Ubuntu 24.04, which uses GNOME 46, while keeping the window controls (maximize, minimize, and close buttons). Here's what I've found so far:
Many popular GNOME extensions for this purpose are outdated and not compatible with the latest version.
I found an extension called "No Title Bar When Maximized", but it removes the window controls along with the title bar, which is not what I want.
Looking For:
Removes the window title bar,
Keeps the window controls, (maximize, minimize, and close buttons)
Works with Ubuntu 24.04 and GNOME 46
Is there a way to achieve this on newer Ubuntu installations?
Are there any up-to-date GNOME extensions that can accomplish this?
If not, are there any alternative methods or workarounds to remove the title bar while keeping the window controls?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Welcome to AskUbuntu! If you want to maximize the window with no title bar, pressing F11 will work on third-party applications. If you are looking for window controls to be available, please attach an example of your expected result.
